# iMac, late 2006 - 64bit Linux OS

Tags: startup, install

In this old post [How can I install a 64-bit OS on a 2006 Mac Pro with 32-bit EFI?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/291516/how-can-i-install-a-64-bit-os-on-a-2006-mac-pro-with-32-bit-efi?newreg=3f954fde879c4268af688ce62b923484), a user asks about the possibility of installing a 64bit Linux OS on an older Mac PC.

Ok, I'm a little late at this party but the Answerer talks about certain risks and issues, what would they be?
And if the installation works (it seems like it :)), would there still be risks?

I talk about this method at [Linux DVD images (and how-to) for 32-bit EFI Macs (late 2006 models)](https://mattgadient.com/linux-dvd-images-and-how-to-for-32-bit-efi-macs-late-2006-models/)

And how about this little C program if I may ask, is it clean?

These old 2006 iMacs are still working and kind of fun, so I'd like to install a 64bit Linux on it, without the fear of security risks.
Would be great if someone can give a reliable and also trustworthy Answer.

Comment: Be aware that even if you manage to successfully install and boot Linux on the 2006 iMac, you will very likely experience X.org trouble with the Radeon Mobility X1600 graphics chip and the 1680x1050 native resolution of the built-in LCD panel.
https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/678654/xorg-problem-with-radeon-mobility-x1600-on-a-20-imac-lcd-from-2006/

Comment: sorry for the late response and thanks for your input

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to install a 64 bit Linux without having to modify the ISO image. To do this, your Linux will need to be installed to BIOS boot.

You should be aware of the following.

- Many early Intel Macs needed a firmware update before being able to BIOS boot.
- Your Mac can only BIOS boot from the internal optical drive or HDD. Your Mac can only 32 bit EFI boot from the USB ports.
- Your Mac can only boot from the optical drive if the DVD has only one boot method. For example, if the DVD is capable of both BIOS and 32 bit EFI booting, then the DVD will not be bootable on your Mac.

[This answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/405913/newly-installed-debian-stuck-on-loading-on-macbook-pro-core-2-duo-2-16/409448#409448) outlines the instructions for installing a 64 bit Debian Linux on a Mac with a 32 bit EFI. The basic steps are outlined below.

1. From an USB port on the Mac, 32 bit EFI boot a 32 bit Debian installer.
2. Install a 32 bit Debian to BIOS boot.
3. Copy a 64 bit Debian installer to the internal drive.
4. Use the Grub from the 32 bit BIOS booting Debian to BIOS boot the 64 bit Debian installer.
5. Replace the 32 bit BIOS booting Debian with a 64 bit BIOS booting Debian.

In many cases, you can install a different 64 bit Linux by substituting some other 64 bit Linux installer.

---

Here is [another answer](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/406506/installing-windows-on-a-macbook-pro-15-inch-core-2-duo-without-mac-os-x/407727#407727) where a Windows/Kubuntu dual boot is installed. Here, DVDs are used instead of an USB flash drive.